# My website not working when i do not type www in address bar

Tags: node.js, web, dns, hosting

when I type (my website)linkdresources.com without www in browser it shows blank page but when I type with www.linkdresources.com then open completely how should i resolve this problem?

i hosted my website acually on herokuapp.com (linkdtry.herokuapp.com) and connect it with domain (www.linkdresources.com) but now it's not working with (linkdresources.com)

Comment: Do you want help redirecting `linkdresources.com` to `www.linkdresources.com`? Or setting your server to accept both?

Answer (score 0):

www is a subdomain of linkdresources.com.  In other words it is a different "address".

For more details see this Q/A: https://superuser.com/questions/60006/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-www-subdomain

You could redirect users to your preferred domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed your A records for your domain name to point to heroku then always add

@ - used to point a root domain (linkdresources.com) to the IP address:

A Record | @ |  XX.XX.XX.XX

www - is selected when it is needed to point www.linkdresources.com to the IP address:

A Record | www |  XX.XX.XX.XX

a wildcard ( * ) record that matches requests for non-existent subdomains:

A Record | * |  XX.XX.XX.XX